# css display:inline-block not displaying inline

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/chris2011/Zz9nY/1/

Could someone let me know why the bacground images are not displaying inline?  THanks

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you could be a bit more descriptive.  I'm not sure what your intended result is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to put the _text class blocks into individual _box class blocks per this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/c2wLP/1

Comment: THAnks, Joseph. That's exactly what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Inline to what? You've got the bg image set on the containing h_preview_box. If you want each of those 3 text divs to have the image, then you'll have to set the background on the h_preview_text class instead.